# copy and paste feature for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a feature in which user need can copy and paste the content from browser to another apps using javascript but I am failed https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp
I already use this. please help me in this Thanks in advance

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  // Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

   // Copy the text inside the text field
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);

  // Alert the copied text
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` returns a Promise that is rejected when it fails. [Check the error](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrqoc7be/) to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I already check but it not working